# scraping with jsoup in android studios don t get all the html

Tags: java, android, web-scraping, connection, jsoup

i was trying to scraping this [page](http://www.bajarmp3gratis.net/descargar-mp3/cuarteto%20de%20nos%20hielo) but when i try to get all the html code of that page, apparently i only get a part of the html code and really don t understand, because i set the max size of the transfer in the connection of jsoup with the page but it didn t work...(if you think that i need to put more information pls ask me and pls don t downvote without comment something to improve)

here is the java´s code:

```
package com.example.rauldelrio.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;

import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;

public class searcher extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView result;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_searcher);


    result=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
    getwebside();


}
private void getwebside(){

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            try {

                Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.bajarmp3gratis.net/descargar-mp3/cuarteto%20de%20nos%20hielo").header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate").maxBodySize(0).timeout(10000).get();
                //http://www.ytdata.win/Abka4REncYe
                //http://www.ytdata.stream/3225352d3038
                //data-id="Abka4REncYe"
                //data-id="eYcnER4akbA"
                //kqJw9wdZ_ng
                builder.append("hola");
                String title =doc.title();
                //Elements body = doc.select("l");
                //String body = doc.data();
                //Element body = doc.body();
                String body = doc.outerHtml();

                String elementText = body;//.text();

                builder.append(title).append("\n");
                //for(Element link : body){
                   // String palabra = "\nLink"+link.text();
                  //  builder.append(palabra);
                //}
                builder.append(elementText);

                result.setText(builder.toString());
                Log.d("aquiesta",builder.toString());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                builder.append("Error : ").append(e.getMessage()).append("\n");
            }
            //runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
              //  result.setText(builder.toString());

            //});


        }
    }).start();

}
```

}

here i will put the part that i get of the html(of the page that i put before) and the output of the console:

```
08/17 23:59:28: Launching app
$ adb install-multiple -r -t -p com.example.rauldelrio.myapplication C:\Users\Raul del Rio\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication3\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_4.apk 
Split APKs installed
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.rauldelrio.myapplication/com.example.rauldelrio.myapplication.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online
Waiting for process to come online
Waiting for process to come online
Waiting for process to come online
Connected to process 4028 on device Nexus_5X_API_28_x86 [emulator-5554]
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
W/o.myapplicatio: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
I/chatty: uid=10083(com.example.rauldelrio.myapplication) identical 10 lines
W/o.myapplicatio: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
I/o.myapplicatio: Background concurrent copying GC freed 6631(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 56% free, 1163KB/2MB, paused 39.627ms total 372.252ms
W/o.myapplicatio: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
W/o.myapplicatio: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
D/OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline
D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe65daf80, tid 4095
I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
               android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xeafdcba0: maj 3 min 1 rcv 4
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xeafdcba0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xe78136b0)
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
I/Choreographer: Skipped 56 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xeafdcba0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xe78136b0)
I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=1816ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=253082941122501, Vsync=253083874455797, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=253083889096570, AnimationStart=253083889201700, PerformTraversalsStart=253083890041690, DrawStart=253084277646410, SyncQueued=253084340510440, SyncStart=253084343805110, IssueDrawCommandsStart=253084351924060, SwapBuffers=253084604427040, FrameCompleted=253084760458960, DequeueBufferDuration=4437000, QueueBufferDuration=2929000, 
I/Choreographer: Skipped 63 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=1132ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=253083911579268, Vsync=253084961579226, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=253084968678890, AnimationStart=253084968770070, PerformTraversalsStart=253085015412190, DrawStart=253085020215380, SyncQueued=253085021627280, SyncStart=253085025713640, IssueDrawCommandsStart=253085026534580, SwapBuffers=253085028127820, FrameCompleted=253085048194870, DequeueBufferDuration=1873000, QueueBufferDuration=14967000, 
V/StudioProfiler: StudioProfilers agent attached.
V/StudioProfiler: Acquiring Application for Events
V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: java/net/URL
W/o.myapplicatio: Current dex file has more than one class in it. Calling RetransformClasses on this class might fail if no transformations are applied to it!
V/StudioProfiler: Memory control stream started.
V/StudioProfiler: Live memory tracking disabled.
V/StudioProfiler: Live memory tracking enabled.
                  JNIEnv not attached
V/StudioProfiler: Loaded classes: 11148
V/StudioProfiler: Tracking initialization took: 1531256800ns
I/Choreographer: Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@9b87c0e
I/o.myapplicatio: Background concurrent copying GC freed 377(274KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 50% free, 2MB/4MB, paused 45.805ms total 444.354ms
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xeafdcba0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xe78136b0)
I/o.myapplicatio: Background concurrent copying GC freed 26602(1254KB) AllocSpace objects, 13(576KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 2MB/5MB, paused 3.680ms total 1.324s
W/o.myapplicatio: Verification of void org.jsoup.parser.TokeniserState.<clinit>() took 1.428s
D/aquiesta: holaDescargar Cuarteto De Nos Hielo MP3 Gratis - BajarMp3Gratis.NeT
            <!doctype html>
            <html lang="es">
             <head>
              <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gb18030"> 
              <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximun-scale=1"> 
              <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en-us"> 
              <title>Descargar Cuarteto De Nos Hielo MP3 Gratis - BajarMp3Gratis.NeT</title> 
              <meta name="description" content="Escuchar y Descargar Cuarteto De Nos Hielo Mp3, bajar mp3 fácil y rápido desde tu celular totalmente gratis."> 
              <meta name="keywords" content="descargar musica cuarteto de nos hielo, cuarteto de nos hielo en MP3, cuarteto de nos hielo musica, cuarteto de nos hielo gratis, musica gratis, musica mp3, descargar mp3, bajar mp3"> 
              <link rel="image_src" href="http://www.bajarmp3gratis.net/cdn.img/share-img.jpg"> 
              <meta property="og:title" content="Descargar Cuarteto De Nos Hielo MP3 Gratis - BajarMp3Gratis.NeT"> 
              <meta property="og:description" content="Escuchar y Descargar Cuarteto De Nos Hielo Mp3, bajar mp3 fácil y rápido desde tu celular totalmente gratis."> 
              <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.bajarmp3gratis.net/cdn.img/share-img.jpg"> 
              <meta property="og:type" content="descargar musica"> 
              <meta property="og:site_name" content="Descargar Musica Gratis"> 
              <meta name="google-site-verification" content="kfgrZ807sBKeQpwfPummX5C12hFp5rAQ8anX5SieHO4"> 
              <meta name="robots" content="index,follow"> 
              <meta name="googlebot" content="NOODP"> 
              <meta name="revisit" content="1 days"> 
              <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="http://www.bajarmp3gratis.net/favicon.ico"> 
              <base href="http://www.bajarmp3gratis.net/"> 
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/estilo.css?v=1521131029"> 
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> 
              <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.bajarmp3gratis.net/js/jquery-min.js?vr=1534561628"></script> 
             </head> 
             <body> 
              <header> 
               <div class="contenta"> 
                <h2 class="top-navigation"> <a href="http://www.bajarmp3gratis.net/" title="Descargar Musica Gratis">Bajar Mp3 Gratis</a> </h2> 
                <form id="search" method="post" class="form" action="http://www.bajarmp3gratis.net/?buscar="> 
                 <div id="form_wrapper"> 
                  <input id="input" type="text" name="buscar" placeholder="Buscar artista o cancion..." autofocus autocomplete="off" required> 
                  <button>BUSCAR</button> 
                 </div> 
                </form> 
                <div class="clearfix"></div> 
               </div> 
              </header> 
              <input type="hidden" id="token" value="3451312d3038,3333212d3038,3343352d3038,3324242d3038,3251232d3038,3451352d3038,3354152d3038,3511452d3038,3314432d3038,3511132d3038,3411432d3038,3142332d3038,3413252d3038,3211432d3038,3233242d3038,3313412d3038,3252422d3038,3425512d3038,3433242d3038,3313212d3038,3341542d3038,3221242d3038,3312132d3038,3423332d3038,3425322d3038,3444132d3038,3124122d3038,3313142d3038,3531512d3038,3311552d3038"> 
              <div class="contenedor grupo main"> 
               <div class="contenido"> 
                <div class="postlist"> 
                 <h1>Descargar Cuarteto De Nos Hielo MP3 Gratis</h1> 
                 <div class="description"> 
                  <p>Descargar <strong>Cuarteto De Nos Hielo</strong> MP3 en alta calidad (HD) <strong>20</strong> resultados, lo nuevo de sus canciones y videos que estan de moda este 2018, bajar musica de Cuarteto De Nos Hielo en diferentes formatos de audio mp3 y video disponibles; <strong>Cuarteto De Nos - De Hielo</strong> MP3 subido por <strong>Nelson D.</strong> tamaño <strong>9.88 MB</strong>, duración <strong>4:13</strong> calidad de 192. </p> 
                 </div> 
                 <iframe style="height: 1px; width: 1px;" id="video" class="full" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/eYcnER4akbA?controls=0&amp;amp;disablekb=0&amp;amp;autoplay=0&amp;amp;wmode=opaque&amp;amp;showinfo=0&amp;amp;rel=0&amp;amp;cc_load_policy=0&amp;amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;amp;iv_load_policy=3" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe> 
                 <ul class="play_lista playlist-new"> 
                  <l
```

Comment: It might be due to the android studio's display buffer length. Try to save the result to a file and check the file's content.

Comment: To make sure the whole page is downloaded try: `builder.append("Is whole page downloaded? ").append(body.contains("</html>"));`